# How to handle shell expansion in docker-compose when setting env variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there an equivalent mechanism in docker-compose to do something like the following:

```
# Pass Env variable based on some expression
ENV_VAR=`some bash expression`
docker run -d -e "MY_ENV_VAR=${ENV_VAR}" myDockerContainer
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose?rq=1