# How can I use environment variables in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I would like to be able to use environment variables inside *docker-compose.yml*, with values passed in at the time of `docker-compose up`. This is the example.

I am doing this today with a basic `docker run` command, which is wrapped around my own script. Is there a way to achieve it with compose, without any such bash wrappers?

```yaml
proxy:
  hostname: $hostname
  volumes:
    - /mnt/data/logs/$hostname:/logs
    - /mnt/data/$hostname:/data
```

Comment: For different options see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: It's solved in the last version of compose, your example will work just as is. check https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution about variable substitution.

Comment: Don't forget docker-app (since June 2018): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007138/6309

Answer (score 122, accepted):

1. Create a `template.yml`, which is your `docker-compose.yml` with environment variable.
2. Suppose your environment variables are in a file 'env.sh'
3. Put the below piece of code in a sh file and run it.

```bash
source env.sh
rm -f docker-compose.yml
envsubst < "template.yml" > "docker-compose.yml"
```

A new file `docker-compose.yml` will be generated with the correct values of environment variables.

Sample `template.yml` file:

```
oracledb:
        image: ${ORACLE_DB_IMAGE}
        privileged: true
        cpuset: "0"
        ports:
                - "${ORACLE_DB_PORT}:${ORACLE_DB_PORT}"
        command: /bin/sh -c "chmod 777 /tmp/start; /tmp/start"
        container_name: ${ORACLE_DB_CONTAINER_NAME}
```

Sample `env.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash 
export ORACLE_DB_IMAGE=<image-name> 
export ORACLE_DB_PORT=<port to be exposed> 
export ORACLE_DB_CONTAINER_NAME=ORACLE_DB_SERVER
```

Comment: still no better solution at the moment?

Comment: why would you recursively delete a file? (rm -rf docker-compose.yml)

Comment: -1 this solution only complicates things and should be updated according to docker-compose new abilities https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files

Comment: I would recommend using the above command inside the parenthesis so that even the variable will not be set globally. Ex. `(source env.sh; rm -rf docker-compose.yml; envsubst < "template.yml" > "docker-compose.yml";)`

Comment: This answer is out of date.

Answer (score 425):

It seems that docker-compose has native support now for [default environment variables in a file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

All you need to do is declare your variables in a file named `.env` and they will be available in *docker-compose.yml*.

For example, for a `.env` file with contents:

```
MY_SECRET_KEY=SOME_SECRET
IMAGE_NAME=docker_image
```

You could access your variable inside `docker-compose.yml` or forward them into the container:

```yaml
my-service:
  image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
  environment:
    MY_SECRET_KEY: ${MY_SECRET_KEY}
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I don't know why but the file name should be literally `.env`, for example `config.env` did not worked for me.

Comment: @HBat the "." means a hidden file -- this is usual procedure for local config files

Comment: The best solution. and We could add /etc/environment props and use those as an environment with using .env. That'll be more secure.

Comment: @HBat, you can use `env_file` for that, e.g.: `env_file: config.env`

Comment: Be aware that `Values set in the shell environment override those set in the .env file.`. That means: default values for environment variables should be in `.env`, if you want to overwrite them look for modulitos answer.

Comment: *.env* is for variables that are parsed in to the *docker-compose.yml* interpreter, not for the container. For variables to be set in the container, you will need to specify a *.env* file in your *docker-compose.yml* using `env_file: .env.vars` or whatever your file name is that contains the variables. It's a confusing antipattern to use `env_file: .env` which works but basically uses the variables both for the interpreter and the container.

Comment: @PeterKionga-Kamau But is this really always an anti-pattern? I'd rather have people who want to deploy my application only set up *one* .env file (e.g. from a template) than instructing them to but certain variables in certain files. It's *my* job to choose the variable names in a way there are no conflicts then. Basically, if I know what I'm doing, setting `env_file: .env` can make the whole setup much more "streamlined".

Comment: @bkis It's an anti-pattern because despite appearing to be easier and/or adequate, proper use requires knowledge that is not obvious or well documented, and can lead to confusion (few people are aware that there are actually separate files for the yaml parse and the build part until they run into issues). There are also security concerns; it's generally poor practice to allow variables that are no longer needed to persist through to the final build image/containers.

Comment: Is `MY_SECRET_KEY: ${MY_SECRET_KEY}` supposed to work, as I just get an error, and the official docs use a `MY_SECRET_KEY=${MY_SECRET_KEY}` format: 
  https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#additional-information ? Can't submit an edit as the edit queue is full.

Comment: This also seems to work with your current shell's environment variables. I was able to use `${USER}` in my `docker-compose.yaml` file as well, which I did _not_ have in my `.env` file.

Comment: @dtasev yes, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#environment

Answer (score 387):

### The *Docker* solution:

Docker-compose 1.5+ has enabled variables substitution: *[Releases · docker/compose](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases)*

The latest Docker Compose allows you to access environment variables from your compose file. So you can source your environment variables, then run Compose like so:

```
set -a
source .my-env
docker-compose up -d
```

For example, assume we have the following `.my-env` file:

```
POSTGRES_VERSION=14
```

(or pass them via command-line arguments when calling `docker-compose`, like so: `POSTGRES_VERSION=14 docker-compose up -d`)

Then you can reference the variables in `docker-compose.yml` using a `${VARIABLE}` syntax, like so:

```
db:
  image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"
```

And here is more information from the documentation, taken from *[Compose file specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)*

> When you run docker-compose up with this configuration, Compose looks
> for the POSTGRES_VERSION environment variable in the shell and
> substitutes its value in. For this example, Compose resolves the image
> to postgres:9.3 before running the configuration.
>
> If an environment variable is not set, Compose substitutes with an
> empty string. In the example above, if POSTGRES_VERSION is not set,
> the value for the image option is postgres:.
>
> Both $VARIABLE and ${VARIABLE} syntax are supported. Extended
> shell-style features, such as ${VARIABLE-default} and
> ${VARIABLE/foo/bar}, are not supported.
>
> If you need to put a literal dollar sign in a configuration value, use
> a double dollar sign ($$).

The feature was added [in this pull request](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1765).

#### Alternative Docker-based solution: Implicitly sourcing an environment variables file through the `docker-compose` command

If you want to avoid any [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) wrappers, or having to source a environment variables file explicitly (as demonstrated above), then you can pass a `--env-file` flag to the `docker-compose` command with the location of your environment variable file: *[Use an environment file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/)*

Then you can reference it within your `docker-compose` command without having to source it explicitly:

```
docker-compose --env-file .my-env  up -d
```

If you don't pass a `--env-file` flag, the default environment variable file will be `.env`.

Note the following caveat with this approach:

> Values present in the environment at runtime always override those defined inside the .env file. Similarly, values passed via command-line arguments take precedence as well.

So be careful about any environment variables that may override the ones defined in the `--env-file`!

### The *Bash* solution:

I notice that Docker's automated handling of environment variables can cause confusion. Instead of dealing with environment variables in Docker, let's go back to basics, like Bash! Here is a method using a Bash script and a `.env` file, with some extra flexibility to demonstrate the utility of environment variables:

```
POSTGRES_VERSION=14
# Note that the variable below is commented out and will not be used:
# POSTGRES_VERSION=15

# You can even define the compose file in an environment variable like so:
COMPOSE_CONFIG=my-compose-file.yml
# You can define other compose files, and just comment them out
# when not needed:
# COMPOSE_CONFIG=another-compose-file.yml
```

Then run this Bash script in the same directory, which should deploy everything properly:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker rm -f `docker ps -aq -f name=myproject_*`
set -a
source .env
cat ${COMPOSE_CONFIG} | envsubst | docker-compose -f - -p "myproject" up -d
```

Just reference your environment variables in your compose file with the usual Bash syntax (ie `${POSTGRES_VERSION}` to insert the `POSTGRES_VERSION` from the `.env` file).

While this solution involves Bash, some may prefer it because it has better [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Note the `COMPOSE_CONFIG` is defined in my `.env` file and used in my Bash script, but you can easily just replace `{$COMPOSE_CONFIG}` with the `my-compose-file.yml` in the Bash script.

Also note that I labeled this deployment by naming all of my containers with the "myproject" prefix. You can use any name you want, but it helps identify your containers so you can easily reference them later. Assuming that your containers are stateless, as they should be, this script will quickly remove and redeploy your containers according to your .env file parameters and your compose [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) file.

Since this answer seems pretty popular, I wrote a blog post that describes my Docker deployment workflow in more depth: *[Let's Deploy! (Part 1)](https://modulitos.com/blog/lets-deploy-part-1/)* This might be helpful when you add more complexity to a deployment configuration, like Nginx configurations, [Let's Encrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Encrypt) certificates, and linked containers.

Comment: You can simply `grep foo file.text` instead of `cat file.text | grep foo`. In my case I had to `export $(grep "^[^#]" .config | xargs) && cat docker-compose.yml | envsubst`.

Comment: "I notice folks have issues with Docker's environment variables support" -- do you have any details or a link to a ticket?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't log the specific issue I was experiencing, and it was so long ago (~6 months), I don't know whether it's still relevant. But yes, some features in the Docker environment variable support were buggy, and it was reported by multiple users. I believe it is much better now. But when the deployment configuration becomes significantly complex, I would prefer to modularize it by using bash to handle to configuration logic and Docker Compose for the container orchestration.

Comment: Unless Docker Compose can handle the variety and complexity of configuration possibilities, I think modularizing the config logic separately is more inline with the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy). And I think bash is a great way to handle this problem through the use of config templates and environment variables.

Comment: PSA: This **only works with `docker-compose up`** and not with `docker-compose run`.

Comment: In format 2.1 of the docker-compose file there is also support for default values if the environment variable is not set: `${VARIABLE:-default}`. Link to documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

Comment: There is this solution https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#envfile that I use where you add environment variables from a `.env` under `env_file`. Then you can reference the variables in `docker-compose.yml` using `${VARIABLE}`

Comment: This answer is out of date. You no longer have to SOURCE the environment script. docker-compose does it for you. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to note that these environment variables are for a container launch and not for image building (i.e. `up --build` or Dockerfile). For example, for building: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41848041/5113030 (*Use docker-compose env variable in Dockerbuild file*...)

Comment: This can get wierd very fast! Check [my example to prevent confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74544228/6474744)

Comment: and it is called `docker compose` these days. What is super confusing is what one reads in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/) which uses a different (` - `) syntax for `environment:`

Comment: @theking2 both array and map structures are permitted, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#environment

Answer (score 77):

#### Don't confuse the `.env` file and the `env_file` option!

They serve totally different purposes!

The `.env` file feeds those environment variables only to your *Docker Compose* file, which in turn, can be passed to the containers as well.

But the `env_file` option only passes those variables to the containers and ***not*** the Docker Compose file ‍

##### ***Important note on secrets***

The example is using the environment variables to pass secret credentials to the Docker Compose file. There is a better encrypted and safe way to do this explained in detail in the official documentation: [How to use secrets in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/)

##### Example

1. OK, let's say we have this simple compose file:

   ```yaml
   services:
     foo:
       image: ubuntu
       hostname: suchHostname # <-------------- hard coded 'suchHostname'
       volumes:
         - /mnt/data/logs/muchLogs:/logs # <--- hard coded 'muchLogs'
         - /mnt/data/soBig:/data # <----------- hard coded 'soBig'
   ```
2. We don't want to hard code these anymore! So, we can put them in the current terminal's environment variables and check if `docker-compose` understands them:

   ```bash
   $ export the_hostname="suchHostName"
   $ export dir_logs="muchLogs"
   $ export dir_data="soBig"
   ```
3. and change the `docker-compose.yml` file to:

   ```yaml
   services:
     foo:
       image: ubuntu
       hostname: $the_hostname # <-------------- use $the_hostname
       volumes:
         - /mnt/data/logs/$dir_logs:/logs # <--- use $dir_logs
         - /mnt/data/$dir_data:/data # <-------- usr $dir_data
   ```
4. Now let's check out if it worked with executing `docker-compose config` and inspecting the output:

   ```yaml
   name: tmp
   services:
     foo:
       hostname: suchHostName # <------------- $the_hostname
       image: ubuntu
       networks:
         default: null
       volumes:
       - type: bind
         source: /mnt/data/logs/muchLogs # <-- $dir_logs
         target: /logs
         bind:
           create_host_path: true
       - type: bind
         source: /mnt/data/soBig # <---------- $dir_data
         target: /data
         bind:
           create_host_path: true
   networks:
     default:
       name: tmp_default
   ```
5. OK, it works! But let's use the `.env` file instead. Since *Docker Compose* understands the `.env` file, let's just create one and set it up:

   ```bash
   # .env file (in the same directory as 'docker-compose.yml')
   the_hostname="suchHostName"
   dir_logs="muchLogs"
   dir_data="soBig"
   ```

   OK, you can test it with a ***new*** terminal (so that the older environment variables we set with `export` don't interfere and make sure everything works in a clean terminal)  Just follow step 4 again and see that it works!

So far so good  However, when you stumble upon the `env_file` option, it gets confusing  Let's say that you want to pass a password to the *Docker Compose* file (***not*** the container).

In the wrong approach, you might put a password in `.secrets` file:

```bash
# .secrets
somepassword="0P3N$3$@M!"
```

and then update the Docker Compose file as follows:

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    image: ubuntu
    hostname: $the_hostname
    volumes:
      - /mnt/data/logs/$dir_logs:/logs
      - /mnt/data/$dir_data:/data

    #  BAD:
    env_file:
      - .env
      - .secrets
    entrypoint: echo "Hush! This is a secret '$somepassword'"
```

Now checking it just like step 4 again would result in:

```yaml
WARN[0000] The "somepassword" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
name: tmp                       #       ^
services:                       #       |
  foo:                          #       |
    entrypoint:                 #       |
    - echo                      #       |
    - Hush! This is a secret '' # <---- ‍ Oh no!
    environment:
      dir_data: soBig
      dir_logs: muchLogs
      somepassword: 0P3N$$3$$@M! # <---  Huh?!
      the_hostname: suchHostName
    hostname: suchHostName
    image: ubuntu
    networks:
      default: null
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: /mnt/data/logs/muchLogs
      target: /logs
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
    - type: bind
      source: /mnt/data/soBig
      target: /data
      bind:
        create_host_path: true
networks:
  default:
    name: tmp_default
```

So as you can see, the `$somepassord` variable is only passed to the container, and ***not*** the Docker Compose file.

###### Wrapping up

You can pass environment variables to Docker Compose files in two ways:

1. By exporting the variable to the terminal before running docker compose.
2. By putting the variables inside `.env` file.

The `env_file` option only passes those extra variables to the *containers*  and not the compose file

##### Useful links

- Using *different* environment files for production and development with the `--env-file` command, more on [Ways to set environment variables in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file)
- Since this is important, again, to *safely* pass the secrets to containers, read [Use secrets in Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/)
- Use `.config` files, so that there isn't any need to rebuild Docker images. More on the ['configs' top-level element](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/08-configs/)
- Something weird happened when you set up the same variable in different environment files? This might help: [Environment Variables Precedence](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars-precedence/)

Comment: Title is very explanatory and should be basic knowledge for every developer working with Docker. It wasn't for me until now  

Comment: Yes I learned it the hard way as well  Actually, I researched a bit more after reading answers in this page, and added what was missing

Comment: Use **`docker-compose config` instead of** `docker-compose convert`  for more recent versions

Comment: Ok but I want to keep ALL my env files in a separate dedicated directory, how can I tell compose to read variables from a custom location? It seems that it has been hardcoded to read variables only from the same directory?

Comment: @ruslaniv Hey there. 
- You can specify the path with `--env-file` (more on https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with---env-file).
- If you are trying to keep different secret variables separate, please use the `secrets` approach explained here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/use-secrets/ 
- For different configs (so that you wouldn't need to rebuild the docker image), use: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/08-configs/

Comment: Thank you @Pedram. Note for others, if you want to pass variables to the compose file with a different file (not `.env`) you can do it like this: `docker compose --env-file custom.env up`. This is compatible with having another different `env_file` option inside the compose.yaml file. In other words, with the `--env-file` command you pass a file whose variables can be used inside the compose.yaml file. With the `env_file` option inside the compose.yaml file you can pass environment variables to the containers.

Answer (score 75):

The best way is to specify environment variables outside the `docker-compose.yml` file. You can use `env_file` setting, and define your environment file within the same line. Then doing a docker-compose up again should recreate the containers with the new environment variables.

Here is how my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
services:
  web:
    env_file: variables.env
```

> Note:
>   docker-compose expects each line in an env file to be in `VAR=VAL` format. Avoid using `export` inside the `.env` file. Also, the `.env` file should be placed in the folder where the docker-compose command is executed.

Comment: Best way indeed

Comment: NO. It will not automatically make the environment variables available inside the docker container. You still need to explicitly mention these under environment section.

Comment: It worked smoothly in my case, maybe it has to do with the docker compose file version. I was using version 3

Comment: Worked well for me. Docker compose 2.7.0

Answer (score 50):

The following is applicable for docker-compose 3.x
Set environment variables inside the container

> method - 1 **Straight method**

```
web:
  environment:
      DEBUG: 1
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
```

> method - 2 **The “.env” file**

Create a .env file in the same location as the docker-compose.yml

```
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'postgres'
```

and your compose file will be like

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
    postgres_password: "${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}"
```

[source](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

Comment: I'd like to see a complete example of method 1.  I couldn't make this work, so ended up using .env file (which worked fine).

Comment: What is the difference between `- DEBUG=1` and `DEBUG: 1` methods of variable assignments ?

Comment: @Gagik they're different yaml structures. `- DEBUG=1` is an array element, and `DEBUG: 1` is a map. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#environment

Answer (score 39):

When using environment variables for volumes you need:

1. create [.env](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) file in the same folder which contains `docker-compose.yaml`  file
2. declare variable in the `.env` file:

   ```
   HOSTNAME=your_hostname
   ```
3. Change `$hostname` to `${HOSTNAME}` at `docker-compose.yaml`  file

   ```
   proxy:
     hostname: ${HOSTNAME}
     volumes:
       - /mnt/data/logs/${HOSTNAME}:/logs
       - /mnt/data/${HOSTNAME}:/data
   ```

Of course you can do that dynamically on each build like:

```
echo "HOSTNAME=your_hostname" > .env && sudo docker-compose up
```

Comment: Note, according to the docs: `The .env file feature only works when you use the docker-compose up command and does not work with docker stack deploy.`

Comment: This needs to be in the CONTEXT directory NOT the `docker-compose.yaml` directory

Comment: @Joe, this comment saved my life so to speak. Couldn't figure out why .env file was being ignored.

Answer (score 11):

Since 1.25.4, docker-compose supports the option `--env-file` that enables you to specify a file containing variables.

Yours should look like this:

```
hostname=my-host-name
```

And the command:

```
docker-compose --env-file /path/to/my-env-file config
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```bash
env SOME_VAR="I am some var" OTHER_VAR="I am other var" docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml
```

Use version 3.6:

```yaml
version: "3.6"
services:
  one:
    image: "nginx:alpine"
    environment:
      foo: "bar"
      SOME_VAR:
      baz: "${OTHER_VAR}"
    labels:
      some-label: "$SOME_VAR"
  two:
    image: "nginx:alpine"
    environment:
      hello: "world"
      world: "${SOME_VAR}"
    labels:
      some-label: "$OTHER_VAR"
```

I got it from *[Feature request: Docker stack deploy pass environment variables via cli options #939](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/939)*.

Answer (score 8):

To add an environment variable, you may define an `env_file` (let's call it `var.env`) as:

```
ENV_A=A
ENV_B=B
```

And add it to the docker compose manifest service. Moreover, you can define environment variables directly with `environment`.

For instance, in `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile.myservice
    image: myself/myservice
    env_file:
     - ./var.env
    environment:
     - VAR_C=C
     - VAR_D=D
    volumes:
     - $HOME/myfolder:/myfolder
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
```

Please check here for more/updated information: *[Manuals → Docker →Compose →Environment variables → Overview](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)*

Answer (score 6):

You cannot ... yet. But this is an alternative, think like a docker-composer.yml generator:

https://gist.github.com/Vad1mo/9ab63f28239515d4dafd

Basically a shell script that will replace your variables. Also you can use Grunt task to build your docker compose file at the end of your CI process.

Answer (score 5):

I have a simple bash script I created for this it just means running it on your file before use:
https://github.com/antonosmond/subber

Basically just create your compose file using double curly braces to denote environment variables e.g:

```
app:
    build: "{{APP_PATH}}"
ports:
    - "{{APP_PORT_MAP}}"
```

Anything in double curly braces will be replaced with the environment variable of the same name so if I had the following environment variables set:

```
APP_PATH=~/my_app/build
APP_PORT_MAP=5000:5000
```

on running `subber docker-compose.yml` the resulting file would look like:

```
app:
    build: "~/my_app/build"
ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

Answer (score 5):

To focus solely on the issue of default and mandatory values for environment variables, and as an update to [@modulito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33186458/3517025):

Using default values and enforcing mandatory values within the `docker-compose.yml` file is now supported ([from the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution)):

> Both $VARIABLE and ${VARIABLE} syntax are supported. Additionally when using the 2.1 file format, it is possible to provide inline default values using typical shell syntax:
>
> ${VARIABLE:-default} evaluates to default if VARIABLE is unset or empty in the environment.
> ${VARIABLE-default} evaluates to default only if VARIABLE is unset in the environment.

> Similarly, the following syntax allows you to specify mandatory variables:
>
> ${VARIABLE:?err} exits with an error message containing err if VARIABLE is unset or empty in the environment.
> ${VARIABLE?err} exits with an error message containing err if VARIABLE is unset in the environment.

> Other extended shell-style features, such as ${VARIABLE/foo/bar}, are not supported.

Answer (score 5):

This was written for Docker v20, using the `docker compose` v2 commands.

I was having a similar roadblock and found that the `--env-file` parameter ***only*** **works** for `docker compose config` command. On top of that using the docker compose `env_file` variable, still forced me to repeat values for the variables, when wanting to reuse them in other places than the Dockerfile such as `environment` for `docker-compose.yml`. I just wanted one source of truth, my `.env`, with the ability to swap them per deployment stage. So here is how I got it to work, basically use `docker compose config` to generate a base `docker-compose.yml` file that will pass `ARG` into `Dockerfile`'s.

**.local.env** This would be your `.env`, I have mine split for different deployments.

```
DEVELOPMENT=1
PLATFORM=arm64
```

**docker-compose.config.yml** - This is my core docker compose file.

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/apache2/Dockerfile
      args:
        - PLATFORM=${PLATFORM}
        - DEVELOPMENT=${DEVELOPMENT}
    environment:
      - PLATFORM=${PLATFORM}
      - DEVELOPMENT=${DEVELOPMENT}
```

Now sadly I do need to pass in the variables twice, once for the `Dockerfile`, the other for `environment`. However, they are still coming from the single source `.local.env` so at least I do not need to repeat values.

I then use `docker compose config` to generate a semi-final `docker-compose.yml`. This lets me pass in my companion override `docker-compose.local.yml` for where the final deployment is happening.

```
docker compose --env-file=.local.env -f docker-compose.config.yml config > docker-compose.yml
```

This will now let my `Dockerfile` access the `.env` variables.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

# Make sure to declare after FROM
ARG PLATFORM
ARG DEVELOPMENT

# Access args in strings with $PLATFORM, and can wrap i.e ${PLATFORM}
RUN echo "SetEnv PLATFORM $PLATFORM" > /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
RUN echo "SetEnv DEVELOPMENT $DEVELOPMENT" > /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/environment.conf
```

This then passes the .env variables from the `docker-compose.yml` into `Dockerfile` which then passes it into my Apache HTTP server, which passes it to my final destination, the PHP code.

My next step to then to pass in my `docker compose` **overrides** from my deployment stage.

**docker-compose.local.yml** - This is my docker-compose override.

```
services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - ./localhost+2.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/localhost+2.pem
      - ./localhost+2-key.pem:/etc/ssl/private/localhost+2-key.pem
```

Lastly, run the `docker compose` command.

```
docker compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml up --build
```

Please note if you change anything in you `.env` file you will need to re-run the `docker compose config` and add `--build` for `docker compose up`. Since builds are cached it has little impact.

So for my final command I normally run:

```
docker compose --env-file=.local.env -f docker-compose.config.yml config > docker-compose.yml; docker compose --env-file=.local.env -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml up --build
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Add an environment variable to the *.env* file

Such as

```
VERSION=1.0.0
```

#### Then save it to `deploy.sh`

```
INPUTFILE=docker-compose.yml
RESULT_NAME=docker-compose.product.yml
NAME=test

prepare() {
        local inFile=$(pwd)/$INPUTFILE
        local outFile=$(pwd)/$RESULT_NAME
        cp $inFile $outFile
        while read -r line; do
            OLD_IFS="$IFS"
            IFS="="
            pair=($line)
            IFS="$OLD_IFS"
               sed -i -e "s/\${${pair[0]}}/${pair[1]}/g" $outFile
            done <.env
     }

deploy() {
        docker stack deploy -c $outFile $NAME
}


prepare
deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is a work-in-progress. They want to do it, but it's not released yet. See [1377](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1377) (the "new" [495](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/495) that was mentioned by @Andy).

I ended up implementing the "generate .yml as part of CI" approach as proposed by @Thomas.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple like this:

Using command line [as mentioned in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

```
docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev config
```

Or using a *.env* file, I think this is the easiest way:

```
 web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

[Documentation with a sample](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

Answer (score 1):

Use .env file to define dynamic values in docker-compse.yml. Be it port or any other value.

Sample docker-compose:

```
testcore.web:
       image: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/testcore:latest
       volumes: 
            - c:/logs:c:/logs
       ports:
            - ${TEST_CORE_PORT}:80
       environment:
            - CONSUL_URL=http://${CONSUL_IP}:8500 
            - HOST=${HOST_ADDRESS}:${TEST_CORE_PORT}
```

Inside .env file you can define the value of these variables:

```
CONSUL_IP=172.31.28.151
HOST_ADDRESS=172.31.16.221
TEST_CORE_PORT=10002
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using "sed" in my deploy.sh script to accomplish this, though my requirements were slightly different since docker-compose is being called by Terrafom: [Passing Variables to Docker Compose via a Terraform script for an Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67428084/passing-variables-to-docker-compose-via-a-terraform-script-for-an-azure-app-serv/67436683#67436683)

```bash
eval "sed -i 's/MY_VERSION/$VERSION/' ../docker-compose.yaml"

cat ../docker-compose.yaml

terraform init 
terraform apply -auto-approve \
    -var "app_version=$VERSION" \
    -var "client_id=$ARM_CLIENT_ID" \
    -var "client_secret=$ARM_CLIENT_SECRET" \
    -var "tenant_id=$ARM_TENANT_ID" \
    -var "subscription_id=$ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"

eval "sed -i 's/$VERSION/MY_VERSION/' ../docker-compose.yaml"
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I was seeking for a use case where I could use environment variable in `command:` of docker-compose.yml.

To access environment variable, use `$$STREAM_VERSION`.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  coverity:
    environment:
      - STREAM_VERSION=CCD
    volumes:
      - $GOPATH/src/gitlab.protectv.local/ddx/:/go/Coverity/
    tty: true 
    build:
      context: .
    image: coverity
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "7777:7777"
    container_name: coverity-container
    # TODO: Dynamic value for build version in cov-commit-defects
    command: sh -c "echo $$STREAM_VERSION && cov-build --dir $GOPATH/cvbuild go install && cov-analyze --all --dir $GOPATH/cvbuild --strip-path $GOPATH && cd /go/Coverity/ddf.git && cov-commit-defects --url https://coverity-sj.thalesesec.com:8443 --stream $${STREAM_VERSION} --dir $GOPATH/cvbuild --auth-key-file /usr/local/cov-analysis-linux64-2022.3.0/bin/auth.file"
    
volumes:
  coverity-data:
    #driver: local
```