# Docker compose: Multiple isolated environments on a single host with overridable volumes and ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We have a requirement of creating multiple isolated envs of our app in a single host, using a **single compose file**.

I realized that by [specifying the project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host) using `-p` option we can create multiple isolated envs using docker compose in a single host.

However is it possible to override the  `ports:` and `volumes:` in the compose file for different environment, without having 2 seperate docker compose files?

For instance, I would like to override the following properties, preferably through command-line args.

For *dev* environment

```
ports:
 8081:8080

volumes:
 /etc/myapp/dev/properties/:/etc/myapp/properties
```

For *QA* environment

```
ports:
 8082:8080

volumes:
 /etc/myapp/qa/properties/:/etc/myapp/properties
```

Comment: I think that you can use env variables for it. See more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a template.yml and pass the variables you want to generate docker-compose.yml

First, create a `template.yml` with the following content:

```
version: "2"
...
ports:
 "$HOST_PORT":8080

volumes:
 "$HOST_VOLUME":/etc/myapp/properties
```

Now, you can create a script with the variables you want by environment. For dev environment it would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables to use in template.yml
export HOST_PORT="8081"
export HOST_VOLUME="/etc/myapp/dev/properties/"

# build docker-compose.yml from the template
source env.sh; rm -rf docker-compose.yml; envsubst < "template.yml" > "docker-compose.yml";
```

This will generate a `docker-compose.yml` with the concrete values.

Here's an usage example: https://github.com/bsferreira/mysql-fabric

Answer (score 1):

Needed this as well and stumbled upon this question. There is built in support for isolating environments:

```
Multiple isolated environments on a single host

Compose uses a project name to isolate environments from each other. You can make use of this project name in several different contexts:

    * on a dev host, to create multiple copies of a single environment, such as when you want to run a stable copy for each feature branch of a project
    * on a CI server, to keep builds from interfering with each other, you can set the project name to a unique build number
    * on a shared host or dev host, to prevent different projects, which may use the same service names, from interfering with each other

The default project name is the basename of the project directory. You can set a custom project name by using the -p command line option or the COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME environment variable.

The default project directory is the base directory of the Compose file. A custom value for it can be defined with the --project-directory command line option.
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/#multiple-isolated-environments-on-a-single-host

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) with [Declare default environment variables in file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/).

For example, my compose project structure is

```
C:\docker-compose
└───multiple-envs
    │   .env
    │   .env-dev
    │   docker-compose.yml
    │
    ├───dev-files
    └───files
```

`docker-compose.yml`, file content below, you can set ports and other values using `${ENV_VAR}` syntax. It will automatically substitute by docker compose cli.

You can instruct docker compose to show error message when the `${ENV_VAR}` not set or empty using syntax `${HOST_MYSQL_PORT:?HOST_MYSQL_PORT is not set}`, after `:?` is the error message.

```yaml
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${HOST_MYSQL_PORT:?HOST_MYSQL_PORT is not set}:3306
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${VOLUMES_SOURCE:?VOLUMES_SOURCE is not set}
        target: /mnt
        read_only: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:?MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is not set}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER:?MYSQL_USER is not set}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:?MYSQL_PASSWORD is not set}
```

`.env` file, set `ENV_VAR=VAL` in file called `.env`, let's say for production.

```
HOST_MYSQL_PORT=13306
VOLUMES_SOURCE=./files
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=p419460507
MYSQL_USER=u130085860
MYSQL_PASSWORD=p689273542
```

`.env-dev` file, set `ENV_VAR=VAL` in file called `.env-dev`, let's say for development.

```
HOST_MYSQL_PORT=23306
VOLUMES_SOURCE=./dev-files
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dev419460507
MYSQL_USER=dev130085860
MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev689273542
```

To compose in different config, specify environment file when invoke docker compose cli, `--env-file multiple-envs\.env` for production or `--env-file multiple-envs\.env-dev` for development.

```
C:\docker-compose> docker-compose --project-directory multiple-envs --env-file multiple-envs\.env up --detach
[+] Running 2/2
 - Network multiple-envs_default      Created                                                                                                                                                     0.6s  
 - Container multiple-envs-mysqldb-1  Started                                                                                                                                                     1.8s

C:\docker-compose> docker-compose --project-directory multiple-envs --env-file multiple-envs\.env-dev up --detach
[+] Running 1/1
 - Container multiple-envs-mysqldb-1  Started                                                                                                                                                    11.7s
```