# How to "docker-compose up" for images from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is it possible to pull and start all containers defined in docker-compose.yml? I'm trying to execute `docker-compose up -d my/image`, where `my/image` is a repo on DockerHub, but it says "Can't find docker-compose.yml". I also tried first to pull the image using `docker pull my/image` with the same result

UPD: The image https://hub.docker.com/r/gplcart/core/, source - https://github.com/gplcart/docker-core

SOLVED: It seems docker-compose does not work that way I want. I need to create a directory manually, place docker-compose.yml there, then run `docker-compose up`.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/#define-the-project

I expected that running `docker-compose up -d repo/image` is enough to download and run all defined containers

Comment: Do you have a `docker-compose.yaml`  (or `.yml`) file? `docker-compose` won't work without one.

Comment: Sure, I can run "docker-compose up" for a local image

Comment: Please post your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: https://github.com/gplcart/docker-core/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: Oh you have a yml file, hmm it seems correct. You need to `cd` inside the root directory of your project though, or specify that directory as a cmd line argument to dc: `docker-compose -f your_yml_path build`

Comment: See also docer-app (since June 2018): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51007138/6309

Answer (score 3):

Try logging in to Docker Hub so that Docker Compose knows you want to pull images from there.

From the command line ...

`docker login`

You will be prompted for a username and password. Once authenticated, compose should pull your images from Docker Hub when running `docker-compose up`.

Also, you need to run `docker-compose up` from the same directory where your `docker-compose.yml` file is. Looking at your `docker-compose.yml` file on Github, it looks like you are missing a few lines. You need to specify the version, and `gplcart`, `db` and `phpmyadmin` should be under `services`.

```
version: '3'
services:
  gplcart:
    build: .
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.7
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8181:80
```

Comment: I guess "docker login" for pushing. Anyway it didn't work

Comment: Looks like you are also missing lines in your `docker-compose.yml` file. Updated my answer.

Comment: "Also, you need to run docker-compose up from the same directory where your docker-compose.yml file is" Yes, but how do I get to the directory If I pull a remote image? It would be easy for local images. The whole point of "docker-compose up remote/image" is to resolve all things automatically. Am I wrong?

Comment: As long as you specify the proper image paths in your `docker-compose.yml`, compose will handle the downloading of the images, based on the docker registry you are authenticated with, using `docker login`. You need to run `docker-compose up` from the same directory as where your `docker-compose.yml` file is.

Answer (score 2):

To pull an image use `docker-compose pull <service_name>`, where `service_name` is one of the services listed in your `docker-compose.yml` file

The `docker pull my/image` fails, but should fail with a different error than you noted (you posted a compose error)

In your example, `my/name` is not a valid service name because you can't use a `/` in the service name. Compose would give you a different error.

It's unclear to me what `my/name` represents (assuming you replaced it with something locally).

If you post your `docker-compose.yml` it would help determine what the correct `docker` and `docker-compose` commands should be.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `docker` and `docker-compose` binaries coming from the same package manager. E.g.

```
$ which -a docker docker-compose
/snap/bin/docker
/snap/bin/docker-compose
```

In other words, if you've installed *Docker* from a *Snap*, `docker-compose` binary should be already included (`ls /snap/docker/current/bin/`). When using Apt repository, `docker-compose` can be installed separately, so don't interchange binaries between *Snap* with *Apt*, as well don't mix `docker` with `docker.io` package on Apt.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Can't find docker-compose.yml` indicates that you are not currently in the directory with your docker-compose.yml file, or that you have named the file something different. If you have named the file something different, including a different case or extension, you can either rename the file, or run `docker-compose -f your_filename.yml up` to pass a different file for `docker-compose` to parse. If you are not in the directory, make sure to cd into that directory before running `docker-compose` commands.

Answer (score 0):

`docker-compose` acts based on your local `docker-compose.yml` file. Pulling a third-party image with `docker-compose` is usually useful when, instead of executing separate `docker` commands (in order to pull an image or deploy your app, etc etc), you want to define your architecture in a more structured way like:

My `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:

    containerA:
        image: gplcart/core

    containerB:
        build: .
        # go on defining the rest ...
```

and deploying with:

`docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest working example of `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world
```

Which should produce the following results:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "docker_default" with the default driver
Creating docker_hello-world_1 ... done
Attaching to docker_hello-world_1
hello-world_1  |
hello-world_1  | Hello from Docker!
hello-world_1  | This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
hello-world_1  |
hello-world_1  | To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
hello-world_1  |  1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
hello-world_1  |  2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
hello-world_1  |     (amd64)
hello-world_1  |  3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
hello-world_1  |     executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
hello-world_1  |  4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
hello-world_1  |     to your terminal.
hello-world_1  |
hello-world_1  | To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
hello-world_1  |  $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
hello-world_1  |
hello-world_1  | Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
hello-world_1  |  https://hub.docker.com/
hello-world_1  |
hello-world_1  | For more examples and ideas, visit:
hello-world_1  |  https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
hello-world_1  |
docker_hello-world_1 exited with code 0
```

In case of problems, use the following commands which can help to track down the problem:

- `docker-compose config` - Validate configuration file.
- `docker-compose logs` - Check the latest logs.
- `docker info` - Check system-wide information.
- `sudo strace -fe network docker-compose up` - Debug the network issues.
- `journalctl -u docker.service` - Check the logs of *Docker* service.