# Docker run exit wit code 0 - Node.js & Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've build a small Node.js app with a Postgres database. I wanted to Dockerize it, and everything worked fine when I was using `docker-compose`, now I'm trying to put it on AWS EC2, and I'm using `docker run`, but it doesn't work.

Docker Run command:
`docker run -d -p 80:4000 --name appname hubname/appname`
the container starts and stops immediatly

I'm fairly new to Docker so I guess I'm missing something.

Please find my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as base
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
FROM base as production
ENV NODE_PATH=./build
RUN npm start
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    appname-db:
        image: postgres
        container_name: appname-db
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        ports: 
            - '5432:5432'
        volumes:
            - appname-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ts-node-docker:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            target: production
        volumes:
            - ./src:/home/node/app/src
            - ./nodemon.json:/home/node/app/nodemon.json
        container_name: ts-node-docker
        environment:
            DB_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
            DB_SCHEMA: ${DB_SCHEMA}
            DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
            DB_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        depends_on:
            - appname-db:
                condition: service_healthy
        expose:
            - '4000'
        ports:
            - '80:4000'
        stdin_open: true
        command: npm run start
volumes:
    appname-db:
```

When I do:
`docker ps -a` I see that the container started and exited right after.

I can't find any logs whatsoever it's very frustrating.

Any help/pointer would be really appreciated.

**Edit 1** - Some additional information:

When I'm using docker-compose we can see 2 containers:
[image]

However this is what I have with docker run:
[image]

Comment: I think you have to copy the build artifacts from the first stage of the build (before the second ``FROM`` instruction) into the second stage of the build. That is done using ``COPY --from=0 /home/node/app/build ./`, for example. Refer to https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/ for more information on how multi stage builds work.

Comment: Is there a rationale for not using docker-compose up on your server? I would suggest you stick with Docker Compose, it's easier to control. You may have to stop and delete your existing containers. Often they get stuck and a rebuild of the image never overwrites the old image as it in a perfect world should have done. Run docker ps -a, grab IDs for each and then `docker stop <id>` and `docker rm <id>`. Let us know if this helps first of all.

Comment: Using `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate` also seems to untangle some problems. To get rid of every hanging container on your system, just `docker system prune -f`. Start over again and often the problem is solved.

Comment: @MarcSances thank you for your suggestion, I've tried that with no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: @anatolhiman can you do docker-compose with an image from docker hub?

Comment: Yes, that should work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989882/how-to-docker-compose-up-for-images-from-docker-hub) but I haven't tried. I find it easier to just clone everything straight from the repository.

Comment: ... I meant to say that I usually just have my Dockerfiles in the repository, clone the repo on to the server, and let them pull the images from there once I run docker-compose up --build on the server. I don't see the need for ever using the docker run command. There is a difference between how much stuff you set up in your docker-compose (that works) vs. what you have in your docker run command (that doesn't work, seems to be missing many parts). Docker run simply terminates because there's no app to run, it just installs node.js@14 it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CMD` and not `RUN` when you execute the `npm run start` command. `CMD` runs every time a container is started, while `RUN` is just executed once, at build time.

This means you start the container, but nothing else is started inside of it. So it exits because there's nothing more to execute. `RUN` was already executed last time you built the container.

Use `RUN` for npm install, otherwise it will try every time to reinstall node_modules you already have. But for the start command – do this instead: `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`

In case it could help you I show you my working docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile. Express API with a Postgres DB.

This is tested and works both on an Ubuntu server and on a dev machine (with docker-compose up for both environments). Note that there are two Dockerfiles (dev/prod).

You don't need to add password/user stuff in your docker-compose, you can just include your env_file and Docker/docker-compose sets everything up correctly for you.

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:

# D A T A B A S E #

  db:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    image: postgres
    container_name: "db"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

# A P I #

  api:
    container_name: "api"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: "DOCKERFILE.${NODE_ENV}"
    ports:
      - ${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/usr/src/service
    working_dir: /usr/src/service

# A D M I N E R #

  adminer:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    container_name: "adminer"
    image: adminer:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ${ADMINER_PORT}:${ADMINER_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile.dev:

```
    FROM node:14.17.3
    ENV NODE_ENV=dev
    WORKDIR /
    COPY ./package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    COPY . .
    EXPOSE 8080
    CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Dockerfile.prod is pretty much the same, just change the environment to prod.

I see is that you include the full path from your home directory when copying, try without that. Just copy from the location relative to your Dockerfile at /.

Comment: I've tried the edit you suggested, so CMD and WORKDIR unfortunately I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Try `docker logs <container_id>` and see if there is more info. Are you using docker run or docker-compose up now? If it's docker run you should include a restart policy (--restart) in your command. You can also try `docker inspect <container_id>`. Exit code 0 usually means everything is good, it exited because the process in the container exited. So it might be something wrong with the script you're trying to run with npm run start.