# How to use environment variables inside docker .env file?

Tags: environment-variables, docker-compose

I have a cache folder and the path is stored in an evironment variable: `$LOCAL_CACHE (export LOCAL_CACHE=/home/me/path/to/any/cache/folder)`

Now I want to append some additional folders inside my .env file:

My .env file:

```
LOCAL_COMPOSER_DIR=${LOCAL_CACHE}/composer
LOCAL_NPM_DIR=${LOCAL_CACHE}/npm
LOCAL_BOWER_DIR=${LOCAL_CACHE}/bower
```

My docker_compose.yml looks like that:

```
version: '2'
services:
  composer:
    env_file: .env
    image: composer/composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:${APP_ROOT}
      - ${LOCAL_COMPOSER_DIR}:/composer
    working_dir: ${APP_ROOT}
```

When I start the service with `docker-compose run composer instal. ...` it stops with following error: `ERROR: Named volume "$LOCAL_CACHE"/composer":/composer:rw" is used in service "composer" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

I'm not shure but it seems, the .env file doesn't support the use of variables.

Comment: which OS is on ? OSX? or Linux?

Comment: both (linux and osx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Into `.env` file you can not use variables. Suddenly but true. Actual for docker compose version 1.8.

But you can use variables into `docker-compose.yml` file like

```
volumes:
  - ${LOCAL_COMPOSER_DIR}/${CACHE_DIR}:/composer/${CACHE_DIR}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose) suggest us another way.

Comment: Sometimes you have different systems with different environment variables. My idea was, to normalize the environment variables inside the .env.DIST files and not inside the docker-compose.yml.