# Using environment variable for volume name in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I am using docker compose version 3.3 and want to use environment variable to define the volume name. I looked at a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose), but that seems to be quite old. With long syntax supported in 3.2, is there a way to achieve that?
Here is what I tried in my docker compose file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  target:
    image: "my-registry/my-image:${IMAGE_TAG}"
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: ${VOLUME_NAME}
          target: /data
    ports:
     - "${TOMCAT_PORT}:8080"

volumes:
  ${VOLUME_NAME}:
```

Obviously this syntax does not work as volume name is not substituted in the keys and throws the following error:

> volumes value Additional properties are not allowed ('${VOLUME_NAME}'
>   was unexpected)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is expected behavior - Compose only does variable interpolation in values, not keys. See [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3108#issuecomment-248038373).

In my project I use [external structure](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1):

```
version: '3.1'
services:
### Code from branch develop ###
  applications:
    image: registry.gitlab.lc:5000/develop/ed/develop.sources:latest
    volumes:
      - developcode:/var/www/develop
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 5s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
### PHP-FPM ###
  php-fpm:
    image: registry.gitlab.lc:5000/develop/ed/php-fpm-ed-sq:latest
    volumes:
      - developcode:/var/www/develop
    expose:
      - "9000"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 5s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
    logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
        gelf-address: "udp://${GRAYLOG_ADDR}:12201"
        tag: "php-fpm"
### Nginx ###
  nginx:
    image: registry.gitlab.lc:5000/develop/ed/nginx-ed-sq:staging
    volumes:
      - developcode:/var/www/develop
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 5s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
### Volumes Setup ###
volumes:
  developcode:
    external:
      name: code-${VER}
```

but first of all I need create external volume manually, e. g.:

```
export VER=1.1 && docker volume create --name code-$VER
```

You can see created volume:

```
docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               code-1.0
local               code-1.1
```

And after that, deploy services using:

```
env $(cat .env | grep ^[A-Z] | xargs) docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth --compose-file docker-compose.yml MY_STACK
```

Comment: Note in newer [versions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#external): "the `external.name` property is deprecated in favor of simply using the `name` property."

Answer (score 25):

If you want to avoid conflicts between different projects, you just need to specify `--project-name "your_project_name"` for docker-compose. It adds namespace for all services and volumes.

For example, you may use the same `docker-compose.yml` for few projects:

```yaml
volumes:
    dbdata_mysql:

services:
    mysql_db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        volumes:
            - "dbdata_mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

If you start your projects with:

```bash
docker-compose --project-name "first_project" up -d
docker-compose --project-name "second_project" up -d
```

it will create namespaced volumes:

```bash
$ docker volume ls | grep dbdata_mysql

local     first_project_dbdata_mysql
local     second_project_dbdata_mysql
```

Comment: THAT's the answer! please upvote

Comment: Awesome find! I also discovered that you can set an environment variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` to override the project name.  And I suspect you can probably put that in a `.env` file for a more persistent setting.

Comment: How to do it with `docker stack deploy`?

Answer (score 9):

This is how I got it done for my case
inside .env

```
# To use a code volume create the volume mapping an existing folder like this and pass the value of <volume_name> below
# docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=<full_path_to_folder> --opt o=bind <volume_name>
PROJECT_VOLUME_CODE=myproject_code
```

then inside docker-compose.yml (version 3.7) or higher
Inside the service

```
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: code
        target: /var/www/html
```

Outside

```
volumes:
  code:
    external: true
    name: ${PROJECT_VOLUME_CODE}
```

Comment: This is the correct way, and it works without using .env files too

Comment: I get `external volume not found` when doing this in 3.8 on ubuntu. Did anything change between 3.7 and 3.8?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to use environment variables with this syntax:

```
volumes:
    - "$HOME/.cache/composer:/tmp/composer_cache"
```

Comment: This is golden!  It will take the value from a `.env` file and if you want to use a default value in case there is nothing set in the `.env` file this is the format 
`- "${PGVECTOR_PATH:-./localdev/postgres_pgvector}:/var/lib/postgresql/data/"`

Using this we can all share the same docker compose file and adjust the path locations at a user level without it getting checked into the code base as `.env` files should be added to gitingore.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change complex stuff between environments, like using completely different volume settings, you should **override your configuration** with [multiple docker-compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

Environment variables should be used for simple values only.

Using multiple configuration files lets you define a default `docker-compose.yml` file with your base configuration, and another `docker-compose.override.yml` for the changes you need for a particular environment.

Then, when creating the services, docker compose will merge the configuration files.

In your case, your default configuration might look like this:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.3'
services:
  target:
    image: "my-registry/my-image:${IMAGE_TAG}"
    volumes:
        - type: volume
          source: vprod
          target: /data
    ports:
     - "80:8080"

volumes:
  vprod:
```

And your dev override file may look like this:

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
services:
  target:
    volumes:
        - source: vdev
          target: /data
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  vdev:
```

Notice that not all services and not all keys need to be repeated in the override file.

When you run `docker-compose up` both configurations will be merged with the override file taking precedence.

Docker compose picks up `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` by default, if you have more files, or files with different names, you need to specify them in order:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.custon.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d
```