# How user variable inside another variable in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a **.env** file like this:

```
PROJECT_DIR=./test_dir
SUB_DIR=$(PROJECT_DIR)/sub_dir
```

And **docker-compose.yml** file like this:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
    service_nginx:
        image: nginx
        volumes:
            - ${SUB_DIR}:/var/www/html
```

But I can't use $SUB_DIR in docker-compose.yml file for volume, I got error like this:

```
ERROR: Named volume "$(PROJECT_DIR)/sub_dir:/var/www/html:rw" is used in service "service_nginx" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using environment variable for volume name in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103843/using-environment-variable-for-volume-name-in-docker-compose)

Comment: You could try [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2636#issuecomment-363688635).

Comment: @DelenaMalan Yes, it not worked for me.

Comment: How did it not work for you? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I don't have problem with using variable. The problem is there is a variable inside the variable

Comment: Oh all right, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

Update your env file as follows

```
export PROJECT_DIR=./test_dir
export SUB_DIR=$(PROJECT_DIR)/sub_dir
```

Then run the following command to read the varialbes;

```
. ./.env
```

Then deploy the stack from **same terminal session**.