# Docker-compose not passing environment variables to docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Python app that uses environment variables and I want make dev\prod setup with one Dockerfile and one docker-compose.yml file (only change env file with environment variables).

Here are the files I use to start the application:
**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
RUN apt-get update

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/excel_users_dump
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN python /usr/src/app/myblumbot/main.py
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  bot:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      ENV: ${ENV}
      PYTHONPATH: ${PYTHONPATH}
      PYTHONBUFFERED: ${PYTHONBUFFERED}
    volumes:
      - states:/var/myblumbot_states

volumes:
  states:
```

**.env (in the same directory as docker-compose.yml)**

```
PYTHONBUFFERED=1  
PYTHONPATH=/usr/src/app  
ENV=DEV
```

When I'm running  `docker-compose up`
command, it builds and tells me that I didn't have some environment variables so application can't start.

```
env = os.environ['ENV']
```

**KeyError: 'ENV'**

But if I add `ENV VAR value` in **Dockerfile**, everything works good.

How can I pass variables from docker-compose and .env file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use environment variables in docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose)

Comment: @Mišo I tried all answers from that question but no success for me :(

Comment: Please edit this question to include the actual text of (especially) your `docker-compose.yml` – not an external link – and the actual behavior you're observing.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've edited the question. Thnx.

Comment: Your `Dockerfile` doesn't have a `CMD`.  (And your `docker-compose.yml` file doesn't have a `command:` either.)  What's the process your container is actually running?  How are you verifying the issue?

Comment: There is a RUN python /usr/src/app/myblumbot/main.py command in my Dockerfile thats starts my app. It cant start because there is not ENV variable in container.

Comment: @DavidMaze as mentioned bellow, I changed RUN to ENTRYPOINT command and everything works well.

Comment: @chopchopa I think this could be a useful article for you https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/ and I think you could share the error message and rename the question title to something like "Docker-compose didn't start with error ..." to not mislead the people :)

Comment: @Mišo Thank you for recommendation. I edited question with error as you suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to follow the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/):

> Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an
>   environment file named .env placed in the folder where the
>   docker-compose command is executed (current working directory)

Try to use `ENTRYPOINT python /usr/src/app/myblumbot/main.py` instead of `RUN...`

Comment: My .env file is placed the same directory that docker-compose.yml file is placed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ENTRYPOINT python /usr/src/app/myblumbot/main.py helped me, thank you!

Comment: Already using entrypoint, though unsure how that is supposed to help as env variables don't even show up with `printenv` in the container....

Comment: please open your own question and i'll have a look. Here the issue was with missing `entrypoint`, but in your case it might be different

Answer (score 29):

When you have a setup with both a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file like you show, things run in two phases.  During the first phase the image is built, and during the second the container actually gets run.  **Most of the settings in `docker-compose.yml` don't have an effect during the build stage**; that includes network settings, environment variables, and published ports.

In your `Dockerfile` you're running your application in a `RUN` step.  That happens as part of the build, not the execution phase; the image that finally gets generated is the filesystem that results after your application exits.  Since it's during the build phase, environment variable settings don't take effect.

If you change `RUN` to `CMD`, then this will get recorded in the image, and after the build completes, it will run as the main container process with environment variable and other settings.

(In comments you suggest `ENTRYPOINT`.  This will work too, for the same reasons, but it makes a couple of tasks like getting a debug shell harder, and there's a standard Docker first-time setup pattern that needs `ENTRYPOINT` for its own purposes.  I'd prefer `CMD` here.)

Comment: Thank you for explanation! I'll follow it.