# How to read environment variables into docker compose from custom location

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know that docker compose can read environment variables into itself by reading `.env` file that must reside in the same directory where the `docker-compose` file is located. Usually this is the root of the project.

I want to keep ALL my environment files in a specific dedicated directory called `envs`.

So I have this setup:

```
\project_root:
    \envs
        .compose_envs.yml
        .django_envs.yml
    main.py
    docker-compose.yml
```

Is there a directive for docker compose to read environment variables from this custom location?

PS: I know I can do something like this:

```
set -a; source /path/to/your/env/file; set +a; docker-compose up -d
```

but I would like to use a docker compose directive and run the container just with `docker compose up`

PPS: this question is not about `-env_file` directive, since this one populates the container with the specified variables, but I want to reference environment variables in the `docker-compose` itself, for example in this section:

```
environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
```

Some good solutions here:
[How can I use environment variables in docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377853/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-docker-compose)
but still nothing about my use case

Comment: `question is not about -env_file directive, since this one populates the container with the specified variables` no? just `docker-compose --env-file envs/yourenv up`

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I will edit the question, since I really want to just run `docker compose up` without any arguments

Comment: `docker-compose() { command docker-compose --env-file "$MY_ENV_FILE" "$@"; }; MY_ENV_FILE=/here/and/there; docker-compose up`. You can throw abstractions at it. Wrap it in a custom script. Create a symlink `.env -> envs/env`. Finally, you can patch docker compose to support a DOCKER_COMPOSE_ENV_FILE environment variable.

Comment: Yes, symlinking sounds like an acceptable solution, I'm going to give it a try!